# How to enable a select_tag based on the option from the check box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox

I have a Ruby On Rails application.
I want to enable the drop down list only if the check box is enabled.
Please let me know a way to do this.

Thanks,
Ramya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with jQuery. Add a `click` handler to your element, and do your checks inside that. Here's an example of checking the checkbox: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.html

EDIT: code could be like this:

```
$("#id_of_checkbox").live("click",function() {
  var is_checked = $(this).is(":checked");
  if(is_checked) {
    // disable
  }
  else {
    // enable
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tempos for pointing me to it.Could you please suggest some jquery script that would enable/disable the drop down list when the check box is checked/unchecked

Comment: I wrote a skeleton of what you could have in your page.